# Accessing columns of matlab matrix and its realization in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I am trying to find a realization of accessing elements of numpy arrays corresponding to a feature of Matlab.

Suppose given a `(2,2,2)` Matlab matrix `m` in the form

```
m(:,:,1) = [1,2;3,4]
m(:,:,2) = [5,6;7,8]
```

Even though this is a 3-d array, Matlab allows accessing its column in the fashion like

```
m(:,1) = [1;3]
m(:,2) = [2;4]
m(:,3) = [5;7]
m(:,4) = [6;8]
```

I am curious to know that if numpy supports such indexing so that given the following array

```
m = array([[[1, 2],
            [3, 4]],

           [[5, 6],
            [7, 8]]])
```

One can also access columns in the fashion as Matlab listed above.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you taken time to read any numpy docs.  I believe there's a quick sheet for wayward MATLAB users.

Comment: hi @hpaulj, so far I haven't found the quick numpy realization of such feather. All I come up so far is trying to rearrange the numpy array into a list (or array) of the form ```[np.array([1,3]),np.array([2,4]),...]``` so that one can access columns matlab fashion like.

Comment: I hope numpy does have such feather. It's quite handy in practice.

Comment: Have you experimented with things like `a[0]`, `a[:,0]`, `a[:,:,0]`?

Comment: Yes, this is the most natural way accessing columns of numpy array. But unfortunately, not what I want.

Comment: Playing with this in Octave I now see that MATLAB is doing some weird stuff, allowing us to use `3` in a dimension that's supposedly just size 2; it's accessing that part of the matrix with a 'flat' index.  When I last used MATLAB extensively they'd barely extended the dimensions beyond 2.  You may need to explain, for `numpy` users, what exactly is MATLAB doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236762/discussion-between-coolgas-and-hpaulj).

Comment: Do you mean "feature" when you say "feather"?

Comment: sorry, yea, wasn't paying attention to the spelling. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to this question is as following, suppose given the array listed as in the question

```
m = array([[[1, 2],
            [3, 4]],

           [[5, 6],
            [7, 8]]])
```

One can create a list, I call it `m_list` in the form such that

```
m_list = [m[i][:,j] for i in range(m.shape[0]) for j in range(m.shape[-1])]
```

This will output `m_list` in the form such that

```
m_list = [array([1, 3]), array([2, 4]), array([7, 9]), array([ 8, 10])]
```

Now we can access elements of `m_list` exactly as the fashion as Matlab as listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [41]: m = np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,2,2)
In [42]: m
Out[42]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

Indexing the equivalent blocks:

```
In [47]: m[0,:,0]
Out[47]: array([1, 3])
In [48]: m[0,:,1]
Out[48]: array([2, 4])
In [49]: m[1,:,0]
Out[49]: array([5, 7])
In [50]: m[1,:,1]
Out[50]: array([6, 8])
```

We can reshape, to "flatten" one pair of dimensions:

```
In [84]: m = np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,2,2)
In [85]: m.reshape(2,4)
Out[85]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
In [87]: m.reshape(2,4)[:,2]
Out[87]: array([3, 7])
```

and throw in a transpose:

```
In [90]: m.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(2,4)
Out[90]: 
array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 8]])
```

MATLAB originally was strictly 2d.  Then sometime around v3.9 (2000) they allowed for more, but in a kludgy way.  They added a way to index the trailing dimension as though it was multidimensional.  In another recent SO I noticed that when `reshaping` to (2,2,1,1) the result remained (2,2).  Trailing size 1 dimensions are squeeze out.

I suspect the `m(:,3)` is a consequence of that as well.

Testing a 4d MATLAB

```
>> m=reshape(1:36,2,3,3,2);
>> m(:,:,1)
ans =

   1   3   5
   2   4   6

>> reshape(m,2,3,6)(:,:,1)
ans =

   1   3   5
   2   4   6

>> m(:,17)
ans =

   33
   34

>> reshape(m,2,18)(:,17)
ans =

   33
   34
```

Comment: This is the most natural way of accessing columns of numpy array. But not the functionality I am seeking. I want, like in the matlab case, I can accessing columns in a 2-d fashion. I can use numbers like 0,1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4 to directly accessing columns.

Comment: But this is not possible in this most natural way.